# Performing Depth first search

Tags: java

I'm practicing on DFS but my code went wrong somewhere that I cannot fix. Here is my code:

```
public static <T> void doSearch(Dimension start, Dimension end, char[][] grid) {
    System.out.println(start);
    while (true) {
        if (checkEqual(start, end)) {
            break; // stop searching
        }
        getPossibleMoves(start, grid);
        doSearch(moves.pop(), end, grid);
    }
} // the end
```

In my `doSearch()` method, I have the "moves" Stack to store moves, the `possibleMoves()` method to find the possible moves that you can make from the "start". But when the `checkEqual()` method checks that I've reached the target, it breaks out of the while loop and goes to the end yet still return to the while loop thus the `doSearch()` method never stops. Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the method is wrong. Imagine that, in the first iteration of the while loop, the "checkEquals" return "false" and you get the possible moves then you do a search on the first possible move. In the next iteration, the same thing would happen: the "checkEqual" will return false and you will re-generate possible moves and you will do a search on the first possible move! This will happen forever.